# How can I create a class that can be added to itself only once?

Tags: c++, class, enums, operator-overloading

Right now I have an enum with 5 base values that I want to be able to combine any of the 5 base values with each other to make a combined value, but I don't want a combined value able to be added to another base value.

For example:

```
enum class Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    White,
    Black
}

Color red = Color::Red;
Color green = Color::Green;
Color yellow = red + green; // Ok; yellow = Color::Yellow (Not sure how I would define this value)
Color orange = yellow + red; // Error; can't add to a combined value

// Note: It would be possible to add the same value to itself
// for example: Color::Red + Color::Red = Color::RedRed
```

I'm thinking this will probably have to be changed to a class with operator overloading rather than an enum, but I'm not sure how to prevent adding a combined value to another value.

What would be an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. If it returns the same class, then you can use all its operators on it. You need to make the addition operator return a DIFFERENT class.

Comment: You don't need to change it to a class, just place the operators at namespace scope.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense to me. Why should the operators on a value depend on how you got the value? `Color blue = Color::Blue` -- you can add to it. But `Color blue = Color::Red + Color::Green` -- you can't add to it. Even though it's the same value in the `blue` variable.

Comment: Do you want the error at compile time or run time?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Compile time error

Comment: @Barmar If I use different classes, would there be a way to keep all the values in the same namespace? I would like to be able to access the values like `Color::Red` and `Color::Yellow` rather than `BaseColor::Red` and `CombinedColor::Yellow`.

Comment: I still don't understand the point. A variable doesn't have any memory of how it got its value. So either they're the same value, in which case you can use any of the operators, or they're different values, and they have to have different names.

Comment: It's like saying you want there to be a difference between `x = 5` and `x = 2 + 3`.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps the color example wasn't the best, but I'm actually using this for an RPG class system where the player can create hybrid classes, such as a warrior and a mage combined. But the player can't create a hybrid of 3 different classes. I would like to enforce this on the programming side of it as well.

Comment: Then I suggest you have two classes: `BaseClass` and `HybridClass`. Adding two `BaseClass` returns `HybridClass`, and there's no overlap between them.

Comment: @Barmar Alright I'll do that, so is there a way I could somehow make a third class that can contain either a `BaseClass` or a `HybridClass`? Such as `PlayerClass playerClass = BaseClass::Warrior`?

Comment: Make both these classes subclasses of a general class.

Comment: Create an array of flags for each primary color and based on which flags are set, calculate the current color.

Comment: @Barmar Could you post an example answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I'm not really good enough at C++ to create a complete answer. I know the ideas, but I'm not sure I'd get all the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do exactly what you ask.

I think you need two separate classes `Color` and `PrimaryColor`. Where `PrimaryColor` has an overloaded `operator+` allowing you to combine two `PrimaryColor`s and return a `Color`.

`PrimaryColor` could derive from `Color` so that functions that don't need to combine them can treat them one and the same.

You probably want to protect the constructors otherwise your restrictions can easily be circumvented.

```
class PrimaryColor;

class Color {
  int r, g, b;
  explicit Color(int r, int g, int b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
public:
  friend bool operator==(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs) {
    return lhs.r == rhs.r && lhs.g == rhs.g && lhs.b == rhs.b;
  }

  static Color createYellow() { return Color{1, 1, 0}; }
  static Color createMagenta() { return Color{1, 0, 1}; }
  static Color createCyan() { return Color{0, 1, 1}; }    

  friend class PrimaryColor;    
  const static PrimaryColor Red;
  const static PrimaryColor Green;
  const static PrimaryColor Blue;
  const static Color Yellow;
  const static Color Magenta;
  const static Color Cyan;    
};

class PrimaryColor : public Color {
  explicit PrimaryColor(int r, int g, int b) : Color(r, g, b) {}    
public:
  Color operator+(const PrimaryColor& rhs) const {
    return Color(r+rhs.r, g+rhs.g, b+rhs.b);
  }

  static PrimaryColor createRed() { return PrimaryColor{1, 0, 0}; }
  static PrimaryColor createGreen() { return PrimaryColor{0, 1, 0}; }
  static PrimaryColor createBlue() { return PrimaryColor{0, 0, 1}; }
};

const PrimaryColor Color::Red = PrimaryColor::createRed();
const PrimaryColor Color::Green = PrimaryColor::createGreen();
const PrimaryColor Color::Blue = PrimaryColor::createBlue();

const Color Color::Yellow = Color::createYellow();
const Color Color::Magenta = Color::createMagenta();
const Color Color::Cyan = Color::createCyan();
```

By declaring the static `PrimaryColor` and `Color` variables inside the `Color` class you get something approaching the syntax you asked for:

```
void func(const Color& c1, const Color& c2);

int main() {
  auto red = Color::Red;
  auto green = Color::Green;
  auto yellow = red + green; // Ok
  assert(yellow == Color::Yellow);

  //auto orange = yellow + red; // Error; can't add to a combined value

  auto redred = Color::Red + Color::Red;

  func(red, yellow);  // Pass a PrimaryColor to a function taking a Color
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xyKQHKTTlCaGbKen).

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you could have `PrimaryColor` and `HybridColor` which both derive from a common base class `Color`:

```
class PrimaryColor;
class HybridColor;

class Color {
protected:
  int r, g, b;
  explicit Color(int r, int g, int b) : r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
public:
  friend bool operator==(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs) {
    return lhs.r == rhs.r && lhs.g == rhs.g && lhs.b == rhs.b;
  }  
  const static PrimaryColor Red;
  const static PrimaryColor Green;
  const static PrimaryColor Blue;
  const static HybridColor Yellow;
  const static HybridColor Magenta;
  const static HybridColor Cyan;    
};

class HybridColor : public Color {
  explicit HybridColor(int r, int g, int b) : Color(r, g, b) {}
public:   
  friend class PrimaryColor;
  static HybridColor createYellow() { return HybridColor{1, 1, 0}; }
  static HybridColor createMagenta() { return HybridColor{1, 0, 1}; }
  static HybridColor createCyan() { return HybridColor{0, 1, 1}; }  
};

class PrimaryColor : public Color {
  explicit PrimaryColor(int r, int g, int b) : Color(r, g, b) {}    
public:
  HybridColor operator+(const PrimaryColor& rhs) const {
    return HybridColor(r+rhs.r, g+rhs.g, b+rhs.b);
  }
  static PrimaryColor createRed() { return PrimaryColor{1, 0, 0}; }
  static PrimaryColor createGreen() { return PrimaryColor{0, 1, 0}; }
  static PrimaryColor createBlue() { return PrimaryColor{0, 0, 1}; }
};

const PrimaryColor Color::Red = PrimaryColor::createRed();
const PrimaryColor Color::Green = PrimaryColor::createGreen();
const PrimaryColor Color::Blue = PrimaryColor::createBlue();

const HybridColor Color::Yellow = HybridColor::createYellow();
const HybridColor Color::Magenta = HybridColor::createMagenta();
const HybridColor Color::Cyan = HybridColor::createCyan();
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Sud43LBiVtWtDjja).

Comment: Thanks, the second example is pretty close to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this will take operator overloading. Then, you add a private bool to your class. When you return an added value, the bool gets set to true, signifying that it was previously added.
Ex.

```
class oneAdd
{
private:
    bool hasAdded;
public:
    int member;
    void setAdded() { hasAdded = true; }
    oneAdd operator+(const oneAdd& toAdd)
    { 
        if (!hasAdded) {
            oneAdd ret;
            ret.member = member + toAdd.member;
            ret.setAdded();
            return ret;
        } else {
            // Throw some error. This operator shouldn't have been called.
        }
    }
};
```